# JSON toString() returns bad data exception

Tags: d

I get the following exception

> std.json.JSONException@/build/src/ldc/runtime/phobos/std/json.d(1170): Illegal control character.

When I run this code

```d
import std.json;
void main(string[] args)
{
  auto x = JSONValue(decodeComponent("%C2%8C")).toString();
}
```

There are unicode characters but no control characters. For some reason the unicode `\uc28c` gets turned into `\u008c` and then when it does a `toString()` it says `\x00` is a control character so die.

I'm running this code in a loop url decoding the key value pairs from url query strings and sometimes the values contain unicode. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Use https://github.com/s-ludwig/std_data_json instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

std.uri.decodeComponent assumes that percent encoded values are in UTF-8.

0xC2 0x8C is not the UTF-8 encoding of U+C28C (HANGUL SYLLABLE SYUN). That would be 0xEC 0x8A 0x8C.

0xC2 0x8C is the UTF-8 encoding of U+008C (PARTIAL LINE BACKWARD), which is a control character.

Comment: Thank you anonymous user